# Can you add rows to table async from a pre-generated data set?

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I need to display a table of data. There are potentially many hundreds of rows and it's taking a couple seconds to render them all. During which time, the UI feels like it's frozen.

The data is already in memory, so I imagine that it's just the rendering part that is taking the time.

I was thinking that if the users could SEE each row being added to the table, it would feel less bad. Here's the general code concept.

```
@if (MyList!= null)
{
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Date</th>
            <th scope="col">ExtraData</th>
            @if (ExtraData == DataType.Good)
            {
                <th scope="col">Good Data</th>
            }
            @if (ExtraData == DataType.Bad)
            {
                <th scope="col">Bad Data</th>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var c in MyList)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@c.Name</td>
                <td>@c.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                <td>@c.Data.ToString()</td>
                @if (ExtraData == DataType.Good)
                {
                    <td>c.GoodData.ToString()</td>
                }
                @if (ExtraData == DataType.Bad)
                {
                    <td>c.BadData.ToString()</td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
}
else
{
<div>Loading...</div>
}

@code {
[Parameter] public List<Data> MyList{ get; set; }
[Parameter] public DataType ExtraData { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: There is no way there can be that much data on the screen visible. So why not just page the data you have in memory?

Comment: @orak Because.... end user requirements.  When was the last time you got a argumentative end user to agree to something? :)

Comment: @Orak I do wonder, though, if you're not on to something there.  Put the render in some kind of async loop where it renders 100 at a time?  That's the nature of my question... how do do that.

Comment: I just saw they are adding a new component to handle list vitualization in an upcoming release for blazor in .net core 5.0.

Comment: @Orak That's cool, do you happen to have a release note link handy?

Comment: I saw it in this video starting at about the 50 minute mark: https://youtu.be/KRNd8JDRqRc

Comment: Finally : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-5-release-candidate-1/#blazor-component-virtualization

Comment: @BrianParker post that as the answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 0):

How are you loading the data is it using an async call when the component is initialising?

If it is then you can add an extra if statement as follows:

```
@if (MyList == null)
{
    <div>Data is loading</div>                              
(or optionally have a spinner here)                     
}                           
else if (MyList != null)...
```

Comment: As I mentioned, the data already exists in memory.  The delay is in rendering all of the rows.  The Blazor rendering engine waits until everything is completed before re-rendering anything.

Comment: You may want to look into this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/webassembly-performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-3.1#virtualize-re-usable-fragments

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find that particularly helpful.